# How to install libpng and zlib

Tags: png

I'm completely new to Ubuntu. I got installed it because my school uses a lot of Linux type stuff in my school's Computer Science program so I figured I would use Ubuntu on my own machine and just do my code from there instead of the computer labs. However, I'm having a lot of trouble trying to install the numerous packages that aren't included natively on Ubuntu. Can someone help me install the PNG library, libpng and zlib. This is just one of many things I need to get on here but I think I need to first start off with this. I did download both packages, did the tar xf thingy on the download, and looked at the README files for insight on installing the software. I get weird errors though. I first tried installing libpng and the terminal was like zlib isn't installed so I was like ok, I'll just get zlib but permission is denied. Do I need to get root or something? I remember seeing people say root before, but I don't know if it is relevant. I'm really new so I don't understand a lot of these things and it's kinda scary. Please help.

Answer (score 188, accepted):

Open terminal by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>

For libpng, run:

```
sudo apt-get install libpng-dev
```

For zlib, run:

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
```

Comment: tried # sudo apt-get install libpng-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libpng12-dev' instead of 'libpng-dev'
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ghostscript : Depends: libgs9 (= 9.14~dfsg-0ubuntu3) but 9.10~dfsg-0ubuntu10.4 is to be installed

Comment: libpng12-dev : Depends: libpng12-0 (= 1.2.50-1ubuntu2.14.04.2) but 1.2.50-1ubuntu2 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Comment: Got above error so should I go for "E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install'

Answer (score 7):

Ubuntu uses a thing called `apt`, which is a package manager. It installs, manages, upgrades, and removes programs. If at all possible, you should try to **install programs via Ubuntu Software Center**. What you were likely attempting to do was install from source, which is only recommended if you know what you're doing.

Try to get out of the Windows mentality, which is to search google and download an installer. The Ubuntu Software Center searches Ubuntu's online repositories, which are generally guaranteed to work. Programs installed via Software Center or `apt` will also be updated automatically by Ubuntu's Software Updater.

You can install libpng from the Software Center by searching libpng and choosing "PNG Library - runtime". Or from here [libpng12-0](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/libpng12-0/) [image: Install steam-launcher] by clicking "available on the Software Center". Or using `sudo apt-get install libpng12-0` from a terminal.

The `zlib1g` package should be installed automatically when you install `libpng12-0`, because it is one of the `libpng12-0` package's dependencies. The package manager `apt` installs all of a package's dependencies before it installs the package.

Comment: Your answer, while quite informative for a new user, doesn't actually say how OP is supposed to get the packages needed, and so doesn't answer the question. Could you either add commands like hwez has or instruct OP in using USC?