# Why does apt-cache policy claim libpng-dev doesn't exist?

Tags: package-management, apt-cache, libpng

When I run `apt-cache policy libpng-dev` I get output that says:

```
libpng-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
```

**Why?** Isn't this command supposed to show you what version(s) are available for installation?

Comment: Related: [How to check if a virtual package is installed?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/679137/how-to-check-if-a-virtual-package-is-installed)

Comment: Because it does not exist. There are the following: libpng12-dev libpng++-dev libpng16-dev

Comment: Thanks @kyodake (+1), [but are you sure about that?](http://askubuntu.com/a/508937/344828)

Comment: @smeeb: Yes. You can install synaptic and check it.

Comment: OK, looks like you're right, thanks!! Turn this comment into an answer and I'll happily give you the green check! Also wondering: this is an Ubuntu VM (headless)...are there any commands I can run to get the list of available `libpng*` packages (you mentioned libpng12-dev, libpng++-dev, libpng16-dev, etc.)?